# How to combine Angular $parser with $validator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an Angular directive which allows the user to enter a North American phone number in a variety of common formats (such as "1(301) 797-1483" or "301.797.1483"), but stores it internally as a normalized number in the form "3017971483".

I have the `$parser` working: it strips out all non-numeric characters as the user types, and strips off the first character if it's a "1". However, I'd like to add validation to this, such that:

- If the `$parser` can't translate the current `$viewValue` to a valid normalized number (*i.e.*, because it doesn't contain enough digits, or contains unacceptable junk characters), then:

  - `$modelValue` will be empty; *and*
  - the ModelController's `$valid` / `$invalid` flags will be set appropriately, and its `$error.pattern` property will be set to `true`. (I guess it doesn't *have* to be `pattern`, but that seems like the sensible one to use.)

This is basically how Angular handles default validation via attributes such as `pattern` and `required`. But I'm having a devil of a time figuring out how to make this work with my directive.

My code is below; you can also [view this on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWNpyy?editors=101). Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="DemoApp">

  <form ng-controller="MainController" name="phoneForm">

    <input phone-input type="tel" name="phone" ng-model="phone">
    <p ng-show="phoneForm.phone.$error.pattern">Invalid format!</p>

    <p>$viewValue is: {{ phoneForm.phone.$viewValue }}</p>
    <p>$modelValue is: {{ phone }}</p>

  </form>

</div>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
angular
.module( 'DemoApp', [] )
.controller( 'MainController', [ '$scope', function( $scope ) {

  $scope.phone = '';

} ] )
.directive( 'phoneInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function( scope, $el, attrs, ngModel ) {

            // convert human-friendly input to normalized format for internal storage
            ngModel.$parsers.push( function( value ) {
                return normalizePhone( value );
            } );

            function normalizePhone( phone ) {

                // remove all non-numeric characters
                phone = phone.replace( /[^0-9]/g, '' );

                // if the first character is a "1", remove it
                if ( phone[0] === '1' ) {
                    phone = phone.substr( 1 );
                }

                return phone;

            }

        }
    };
} );
```

If you play with the form, you'll notice that the "Invalid format!" message is never shown. **I don't *expect* this code to show it** - that's what I'm trying to figure out how to do cleanly.

I already have a solid regex for determining whether the `$viewValue` can be translated into a valid number - *e.g.*, "1(301) 797-1483" passes the regex, but "1(301) 797-148" does not. What I'm trying to figure out is where/when/how to *perform* this check, and where/when/how to flag the model as invalid.

Simply adding `pattern="^regex_goes_here$"` to my `<input>` doesn't work - that checks the format of the *`$modelValue`* after normalization, which is not what I want.

I've tried a bunch of different things, but nothing quite behaves the way I want, and I'm out of ideas at this point.

**What is the "right" way to combine a `$parser` with a `$validator`?** Surely there's an established pattern for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method passed to $[validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) receives as parameters both $modelValue and $viewValue, which means that you can actually validate by both of them ([pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjvPbb?editors=101) - enter some letters):

```
ngModel.$validators.pattern = function($modelValue, $viewValue) {
  var pattern = /^\d*$/; // whatever your pattern is 
  return pattern.test($viewValue);
};
```

Comment: This works! I knew it had to be simple. Thanks so much!

For the curious, here's the regex I'm using:

/^(1[-. ]*)?\(?[2-9][0-9]{2}\)?[-. ]*[2-9][0-9]{2}[-. ]*[0-9]{4}$/

Comment: Welcome. Broke my teeth on $parsers, $formatters, and $validators a lot in the past :)